# HttpHandler not working in ASP.NET MVC3 web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, httphandler

I've recently taken an existing ASP.NET 3.5 web forms application that was upgraded to .NET 4 last year (and has been running fine) and configured it to also run ASP.NET MVC3 following Scott Hanselman's blog post: [Integrating ASP.NET MVC 3 into existing upgraded ASP.NET 4 Web Forms applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx).  It works well and I've successfully begun to introduce views based on Razor and the existing `aspx` pages continue to work.

The one thing that has stopped working, however, is a custom HttpHandler (our load balancer hits a specific address to ensure the application is available - the handler is for that address).  The web.config has always declared the handler in the `system.web` section like this:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="system/heartbeat.aspx"
    type="My.Monitor.HttpHandlers.LoadBalancerHandler, My.Monitor"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Now we're testing post-MVC3 and I'm getting an exception that reads:

> The controller for path
>   '/system/heartbeat.aspx' was not found
>   or does not implement IController.

I have defined a `RegisterRoutes` method in my `Global.asax` and that method is called from the `Application_Start`.  Within `RegisterRoutes` I've got the `IgnoreRoute` declarations from Hanselman's blog:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
```

which I thought was to prevent the Routing system from taking anything with an extension of .aspx.

I can reproduce the issue in VS2010 as I debug, and the deployment environment is running IIS 6.

What can I do to prevent the Routing system from trying to handle that address so the custom handler can do it's thing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("system/heartbeat.aspx");
```

Comment: Thanks, Darin, that seems to have taken care of it.  I still don't understand why the `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");` didn't do the trick - but I can live with mystery as long as stuff works.

Comment: @BigPigVT, the [following blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/archive/2010/11/11/mvc-s-ignoreroute-syntax.aspx) provides a good insight about the `IgnoreRoute` extension method.